# Calling a file_write after multiprocessing causes issue in one case and not the other

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I'm using a `multiprocessing` pool with `80` processes on a 16GB machine. The flow is as follows:

1. Read objects in batches from an input file
2. Send the entire batch to a multiprocessing pool, and record the time taken by the pool to process the batch
3. Write the time recorded in step 2 above to an output file

To achieve the above, I wrote code in 2 ways:

Way 1:

```py
with open('input_file', 'r') as input_file, open('output_file', 'a') as of:
    batch = read_next_batch_of_lines()
    start_time = time.time()
    call_api_for_each_item_in_batch(batch)
    end_time = time.time()
    of.write('{}\n'.format(end_time-start_time))
```

Way 2:

```py
with open('input_file', 'r') as input_file:
    batch = read_next_batch_of_lines()
    start_time = time.time()
    call_api_for_each_item_in_batch(batch)
    end_time = time.time()
    with open('output_file', 'a') as of:
        of.write('{}\n'.format(end_time-start_time))
```

In the first case, nothing is being appended to the output file despite batches being processed. I'm unable to figure out the reason for this.

Details of `call_api_for_each_item_in_batch()`:

```py
def call_api_for_each_item_in_batch(batch):
    intervals = get_intervals(batch, pool_size) #this gives intervals. Ex. if batch size is 10 and pool size is 3, then intervals would be (0, 4, 7, 10)
    pool = mp.Pool(pool_size)
    arguments = list(zip(intervals, intervals[1:]))
    pool.starmap(call_api, arguments)
    pool.close()


def call_api(start, end):
    for i in range(start, end):
        item = batch[i]
        call_external_api(item)
```

How is Way 1 different from Way 2 when a `pool.close()` is called in the `call_api_for_each_item_in_batch` itself?

Also, I used `pool.close()` followed by `pool.join()`, but faced the same issue.